# Why can’t back ticks be used to extract type defination in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I ran in to the following situation and I couldn't find the possible reason the caused error (`TS1005: ']' expected.`).

```
interface IconProps0 {
    size: string,
    type: string
}

interface IconProps {
    iconType?: IconProps0[`type`]; // use backtick - TS1005: ']' expected.
    iconSize?: IconProps0['size']; // use single quote
}
```

It works fine with TypeScript version **`4.6`** but version **`3.9`** throws the error. Can the older version of TypeScript just fail to understand the syntax?

**Edit**

Add the [minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIIPYgApQwBwGcAGZAbwFgAoZW5Q4ALwgC56wpQBzAGmruRgAnvlbtOILtQC+1aqEixEKdFlwFC5fnWCYQAFREQA-G1U48RYgG0ABsNG2AugG5kAenfIAroRQAjRABrMF0g5ABaZH0AZQBGYmIAVjYAcidU5AgAD1EESAATADptWl0sGKYTMz11K2tUhmZ0t08fP3puABsUAEdvDEgZIA)

Comment: This does also not work in typescript 4.6 - see this [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSWwiQAUoIwBnOAbwFgAoOZxIpAFQE8xgB+ALgJsyFSgG0ABjG7AJAXQDccAPTK4AV0p4ARjgDWMBNj1wAtHHYBlAIwAGWwFZBAcjnO4oHtlQATAHSMLKzElggAXnyChMQiVGLOlOHArkqqGlpwiUgA5gA2eACO6hCojAC+QA)
What is this code expected to do?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code here to be a true [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  Presumably something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0l2w) instead.

Comment: @jcalz Just added the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) of the form `` `foo${Bar}` `` were introduced in TypeScript 4.1 and cannot be used in earlier versions.  They are useful for string interpolation / substitution / manipulation at the type level, and are overkill for just plain string literals.

On the other hand, [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#string-literal-types) of the form `"baz"` or `'baz'` were introduced in TypeScript 1.8.  Unless you need to manipulate strings at the type level, you should probably just use these.